# Is it possible to get the source (key/keyCode) of a (onClick) Proxy/Synthetic event in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to differentiate whether an onClick event was created by a mouse click or an enter press. I'd just check event.key or event.keyCode but my event is synthetic and of type "Proxy".

A very similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481252/react-component-passes-proxy-object-instead-of-event-object-to-the-handler-funct) 1.5 years ago. But IMHO it hasn't been answered properly. Also his code snippet doesn't compile, here is a working one https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qwbwqw ("Tab ~> "enter" in the preview window).

In some cases (mine and this) the synthetic event has type Proxy instead of SyntheticMouseEvent (like the snippet). Is there a particular reason?

With synthetic events being a layer of abstraction, is it still possible to determine the source of the event? Similar to event.key/keyCode?

The only information I found was the SyntheticMouseEvent.type property. But it's value is "click" for both clicks and enter presses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this with `e.detail`. When clicking on it with the mouse it will have the value of `1` (or greater for multiple clicks) and if you press it with enter it will have the value of `0`.

From [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/detail) of the MDN:

> The **`UIEvent.detail`** read-only property, when non-zero, provides the current (or next, depending on the event) click count.
>
> For [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) or [`dblclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dblclick) events, `UIEvent.detail` is the current click count.
>
> For [`mousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) or [`mouseup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseup) events, `UIEvent.detail` is 1 plus the current click count.
>
> For all other [`UIEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent) objects, `UIEvent.detail` is always zero.

---

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
  }

  click(e) {
    if(e.detail === 0) console.log("keyboard event");
    else console.log("mouse event");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.click}>t</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes obviously you can do that. you have access to key, keyCode and target in the synthetic event provided by Reactjs

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     items: [
       { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
        { text: "Learn React", done: false },
        { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
        { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
      ]
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Todos:</h2>
        <ol>
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" disabled readOnly checked={item.done} /> 
              <span className={item.done ? "done" : ""}>{item.text}</span>
            </label>
          </li>
        ))}
        </ol>
        <input onKeyDown={(event) => { 
        console.log(event.key, event.keyCode, event.target)}} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.done {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Check the code snippet. Hope this helps

Comment: You are correct for input elements. What I failed to explicitly mention was that my problem was with onClick events of a button. Those event's don't have .key/.keyCode properties. Chris answer works perfectly though.